# Winsock select error 10038, bind and listen successful

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, winsock2

I'm trying to use Winsock's `select()` function. However, despite successfully creating a socket, binding it to a port and started it listening, select is failing with error 10038 ("not a socket"). I can confirm with TCPView that the socket is indeed listening on port 8080, so I'm not sure why I'm getting this error.

This is some test code that I've added just after successfully using `listen()`.

```
    fd_set readfds;
    SOCKET client_socket[2], s;
    int act, max_clients = 2;

    while (true)
    {
        FD_ZERO(&readfds);
        FD_SET(this->sock, &readfds);

        for (int i = 0; i < max_clients; i++) 
        {
            s = client_socket[i];
            if(s > 0)
            {
                FD_SET(s, &readfds);
            }
        }

        act = select(0, &readfds, NULL, NULL, NULL);

        if (act == SOCKET_ERROR) 
        {
            printf("Select failed: %d" , WSAGetLastError());
        }
    }
```

I've taken out a `break` that would usually come after the `printf()`, just so I could see it easier in TCPView. The state is reported by TCPView as "LISTENING", as expected. this->sock is the SOCKET used by `bind()` and `listen()`.

Comment: You do not initialize client_socket. Copy error?

Comment: Please post the code of creating and binding. In the code that you posted `client_socket[i]=null`, so `s = client_socket[i]` makes `s` null too.

Answer (score 0):

One of the FDs you are selecting on isn't a socket FD.